# localStorage usage in a web Worker

Tags: javascript, html

I have written an application that relies on localStorage for operation. I noticed that after a certain number of writes, the application will not load on refresh - because as I understand localStorage read operations is time consuming.

Instead of re-implementing my data storage design, I have decided to use a web Worker for my read-write operations. But I'm wondering, is access to localStorage available in a Worker thread?

Comment: Because I make preparation before implementation, and while I am planning my next line of action, this question is part of my prep.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can access localStorage via web workers. Even if you could, you will still be limited by the same number of read/write operations. How many R/W do you do per second? I never had an issue with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood, that DOM and window objects are not accessible from a worker, but the following article had introduced a bit of doubt in my mind: [In defense of localStorage](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/03/07/in-defense-of-localstorage/).

Looking at the article more critically and with further research, I understand confidently that the web storage objects are not accessible to a worker. Back to the article, it discussed what can be a possible capability of the API in the future, not it's present capability.

[The other article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh549259.aspx) that helped clarify my doubt states:

> **"For instance, since you don’t have access to the window object from a worker, you won’t be able to access the Local Storage (which doesn’t seem to be thread-safe anyway)."**